# How to copy rows using Excel VBA based upon a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy rows from one sheet to another based upon the following conditions in one column:

1. If a row contains the value "AB" in the column then copy the row into the worksheet, but if the next row has same value in the same column, ignore this row and move on
2. If a row contains the value "NULL" in the column then copy the row into the worksheet - there is no restriction here

I have written some logic, but it is not working - here is the relevant snippet:

```
If wks.Range("N" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "NULL" Or Not _
wks.Range("N" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = optionCode Then

    'Select row in master to copy
    Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select

    Selection.Copy

    'Paste row into new worksheet in next row
    wksCopyTo.Select

    wksCopyTo.Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select

    wksCopyTo.Paste

    optionCode = wks.Range("N" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value

    'Move counter to next row
    LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

    'Remove blank rows
    wksCopyTo.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    'Go back to Master Sheet to continue searching
    wks.Select
End If
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small Sub that you can pass your Range reference and Row on copy worksheet into that should do the trick. If you can't figure out how to incorporate it, blow out your code a bit and I will show you how to squeeze it in.

```
Sub copyrow(rng As Range, LCopyToRow As Long)

If rng = vbNullString Then rng.EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Cells(LCopyToRow, 1)

If rng.Offset(1) <> rng Then rng.EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Cells(LCopyToRow, 1)

End Sub
```

Also, in above code, no need to use select when writing VBA. It's slower and less efficient. 
Line 5 to 14 (counting blank lines and comments) above can be written simply like this

```
Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow))
```